# When using vagrant Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to install open edx with  ubunty 16.04 and I get this error

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "c60f0594-d584-4e0b-b863-2801168e641e", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

this occurs when using vagrant up

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is typically because you don't have VT-x or AMD-V enabled in your BIOS.  Or worse yet, your CPU doesn't support virtualization.

You can test further by installing cpu-checker.

```
sudo apt-get install cpu-checker
```

Follow that with.

```
sudo kvm-ok
```

The output should be able to tell you what you need.

Keep in mind, vt-x can't be nested, so for instance, say you're trying to run vagrant on a cloud instance, in my experience that wont work.  Atleast, for a 64 bit OS.  You'll be able to run 32bit, however, that would be a single core and horrible performance.

Comment: I have a windows 10 machine with virtualbox 5.0 and on the host VT-X is enabled, also on virtual box VT-X is enabled, any idea? I got this when I ran the second command:

Comment: INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used

Comment: then I cant install OpenEDX on Ubuntu ever? I have i7 4970k its a very new processor. :(

Comment: So Ubuntu is running inside virtualbox inside Windows?  That would be the problem, is so.  VTx flags won't be passed again and again using virtualization.  If Ubuntu were a full install you'd have no issue with that processor.  There should be a way to load the vagrant image with virtualbox.  That will be out of scope here.  Or build openedx without using vagrant.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64-bit in my machine. also get the same reply from the last command,          $ sudo kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used