# CPU doesn't have VT. How to run a 32-bit OS in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

1. CPU: Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz × 4
2. HOST OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
3. VirtualBox: Version 5.1.24 r117012 (Qt5.5.1)

This CPU doesn't support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x).
But I'm trying to install a 32-bit Ubuntu. And I managed to run such a VMs on this computer.

Now it fails.

Maybe the problem is in this: VT-x VPID: on and VT-x unr. exec.: on
Or maybe not.

Could you give me a kick here?

**Log**

```
00:00:04.525344 VM: fHMEnabled=true  (configured) fRecompileUser=false fRecompileSupervisor=false
00:00:04.525348 VM: fRawRing1Enabled=false CSAM=true  PATM=true 
00:00:04.525503 VMSetError: /home/vbox/vbox-5.1.24/src/VBox/VMM/VMMR3/HM.cpp(716) int HMR3Init(PVM); rc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX
00:00:04.525514 VMSetError: VT-x is not available
00:00:04.526121 ERROR [COM]: aRC=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:04.526279 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:04.603646 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
00:00:04.757016 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:04.757060 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={02326f63-bcb3-4481-96e0-30d1c2ee97f6} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:04.757118 GUI: Aborting startup due to power up progress issue detected...
```

**showvminfo**

```
$ VBoxManage showvminfo vmvm
Name:            vmvm
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Ubuntu (32-bit)
UUID:            08530445-9c03-415d-8e72-b79fe151506e
Config file:     /home/michael/VirtualBox VMs/vmvm/vmvm.vbox
Snapshot folder: /home/michael/VirtualBox VMs/vmvm/Snapshots
Log folder:      /home/michael/VirtualBox VMs/vmvm/Logs
Hardware UUID:   08530445-9c03-415d-8e72-b79fe151506e
Memory size:     4032MB
Page Fusion:     off
VRAM size:       16MB
CPU exec cap:    100%
HPET:            off
Chipset:         piix3
Firmware:        BIOS
Number of CPUs:  1
PAE:             on
Long Mode:       off
Triple Fault Reset: off
APIC:            on
X2APIC:          on
CPUID Portability Level: 0
CPUID overrides: None
Boot menu mode:  message and menu
Boot Device (1): Floppy
Boot Device (2): DVD
Boot Device (3): HardDisk
Boot Device (4): Not Assigned
ACPI:            on
IOAPIC:          off
BIOS APIC mode:  APIC
Time offset:     0ms
RTC:             UTC
Hardw. virt.ext: on
Nested Paging:   on
Large Pages:     off
VT-x VPID:       on
VT-x unr. exec.: on
Paravirt. Provider: Default
Effective Paravirt. Provider: KVM
State:           powered off (since 2017-07-27T19:53:26.309000000)
Monitor count:   1
3D Acceleration: off
2D Video Acceleration: off
Teleporter Enabled: off
Teleporter Port: 0
Teleporter Address: 
Teleporter Password: 
Tracing Enabled: off
Allow Tracing to Access VM: off
Tracing Configuration: 
Autostart Enabled: off
Autostart Delay: 0
Default Frontend: 
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
Storage Controller Type (0):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
Storage Controller Name (1):            SATA
Storage Controller Type (1):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (1): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (1):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (1):      1
Storage Controller Bootable (1):        on
IDE (1, 0): /home/michael/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-i386.iso (UUID: 3fddbab9-880d-48d4-ab5e-ae5d20a67852)
SATA (0, 0): /home/michael/VirtualBox VMs/vmvm/vmvm.vdi (UUID: 40b5b3e6-2e6b-44b0-b3d4-f18c30a2580f)
NIC 1:           MAC: 08002786B437, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 2:           disabled
NIC 3:           disabled
NIC 4:           disabled
NIC 5:           disabled
NIC 6:           disabled
NIC 7:           disabled
NIC 8:           disabled
Pointing Device: USB Tablet
Keyboard Device: PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:          disabled
UART 2:          disabled
UART 3:          disabled
UART 4:          disabled
LPT 1:           disabled
LPT 2:           disabled
Audio:           enabled (Driver: PulseAudio, Controller: AC97, Codec: AD1980)
Clipboard Mode:  disabled
Drag and drop Mode: disabled
VRDE:            disabled
USB:             enabled
EHCI:            disabled
XHCI:            disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:  <none>

Video capturing:    not active
Capture screens:    0
Capture file:       /home/michael/VirtualBox VMs/vmvm/vmvm.webm
Capture dimensions: 1024x768
Capture rate:       512 kbps
Capture FPS:        25

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size:      0 MB
```

Comment: try disabling vt-x [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16372)

Comment: if it didn't worked for you then use an emulator like qemu.

Comment: Or with that processor LXC . LXC would be light weight and faster, depsnds on what you need the VM for .

Comment: Don't even try running a VM if the CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization. It will be unusable. (Very very slow)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using vagrant Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR\_VMX\_NO\_VMX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779277/when-using-vagrant-stderr-vboxmanage-error-vt-x-is-not-available-verr-vmx-no)